# When should contract global variables be public vs private

Tags: visibility

```
Contract A {
    uint public x = 1;
    uint private y = 2;

    function getY() external view returns(uint){
        return y;
    }
}
```

If a contract has important global variables that need to be queried by upkeep bots, other contracts, and frontends, what is best practice for making the global variable public (with it's own getter created by the compiler) vs private and making a getter function in the contract?

I've read the [solidity documentation](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/develop/contracts.html#visibility-and-getters), Mastering Ethereum, and other resources for when to make a global variable public vs private but all I've found is discussions of when to make a *function* private or public.  It's not clear to me the difference other than needing to make a getter function for private variables.

Comment: Some guidance can be found here:
https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/79419/125103

Answer (score 1):

Private variables do not have a getter function. By default, a function is private.

Only public variables get a getter function from the compiler.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I would say the logic is quite similar as with function visibility, with the obvious exception that public variables generate getter functions.

I personally like to make most variables public for the following reasons:

1. Easier for others to understand how the contract works if they can just query its data directly
2. Don't give the impression that some data is secret by making it `private`. All data is public, either explicitly or implicitly
3. Helps in all sorts of debugging

What I keep private is some internal things which wouldn't help anyone anyway.